# ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'testImplementation()'

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

Android Studio suddenly stops working. [Studio asks me to upgrade my build](https://i.hizliresim.com/bvjzZZ.png). gradle version to 3.4.1. I already did it but it is still giving the issue;

```
ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'testImplementation()'
```

...

```
buildscript {

    repositories {

        jcenter()
        google()

    }

    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

    }

}
```

...

```
ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'testImplementation()'

Possible causes:
The project 'android' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 3.4.1 and sync project

The project 'android' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by your Windows language settings. The code you sent is from `build.gradle(Project:)` file. Instead, open `build.gradle (Module:app)` file, then change all `testImplementation` to `testİmplementation` (with capital İ) under the `dependencies`. Clean and build.

Comment: It doesnot work for me. I know that issues that you said to me. But this issue solved by updates. But I still have the gradle issue that I said above.

Answer (score 0):

I can not use the studio since a month. This is the solution that worked for me;
When I update the gradle version to the lastest it does not work.
Go to the
path \flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle
Do not change the version of gradle (...build:gradle:3.2.1) even if studio wants the update.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {

        jcenter()
        google()

    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

    }
}
```